# XPath Multiple Attribute Condition Variables

Tags: xml, vba, dom, xpath, xml-parsing

Sample XML

```
<catalog>
    <book id="Adventure" Type="Hardcover">
        <other>
            <author name="Jones" id="Adventure">
            </author>
        </other>
    </book>
</catalog>
```

Do these statements make sense? I need a sanity check to see what's going on with all these variables/quotes. I tried to use one of the XPath test sites, but it keeps giving me an error and I'm not sure why.

```
bookVar = "Adventure"
bookStyle = "Hardcover"
bookAuthor = "Jon"

Set my_location = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book[@id=""" & bookVar & """]/author/other/*[contains(name(),""" & bookAuthor & """]")

Set my_location2 = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book[@id=""" & bookVar & """ and Type=""" & bookStyle &"""]

Set my_location3 = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book[@id=""" & bookVar & """]/other/author/*[contains(name(),""" & bookAuthor & """]")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several notes :

- Use `@` at the beginning of attribute name to reference an XML attribute in xpath
- I'd suggest to use single quotes in your xpath since string wrapper character being used is double quotes. That's will make your code looks cleaner.
- `name()` return name of the current context element/attribute, use `@name` instead to reference XML attribute named `name`
- Some of your path doesn't correspond to the exact hierarchy of elements in the XML document

Example xpath queries :

```
bookVar = "Adventure"
bookStyle = "Hardcover"
bookAuthor = "Jon"

Set my_location = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book[@id='" & bookVar & "']/other/author[contains(@name,'" & bookAuthor & "']")

Set my_location2 = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book[@id='" & bookVar & "' and @Type='" & bookStyle &"']")
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, very informative and helpful!